# Custom mouse hit region for CheckBox in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, wpf-style

I have set a custom style for my checkbox, which looks like this (unchecked state):

[image: Image of an expander with a border around it and dog-ear signifying a checkbox]

When the checkbox is "checked", it should look like this:

[image: Image of an expander with a border around it and dog-ear highlighted green.]

What I want to happen is that the user should only be able to toggle it by clicking the checkmark on the top-right corner. Right now, the checkbox will toggle anywhere the user clicks that's inside of the box and not inside of the expander.

Is there a way I can set the mouse-click region for toggling the checkbox to be only around the checkmark on the upper right?

Here is my code as it stands:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="SelectedCheckboxColor" Color="Green"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="UnselectedCheckboxColor" Color="Gray"/>
<Style x:Key="SelectBoxCheckBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                <Border x:Name="border" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="#FF666666">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                        <Image x:Name="image" Width="24" Height="24" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Source="Resources/checkbox-dogear-unchecked.png"/>
                    </Grid>

                    <!--<BulletDecorator Background="Transparent" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                            <Themes:BulletChrome BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" IsChecked="{TemplateBinding IsChecked}" RenderMouseOver="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}" RenderPressed="{TemplateBinding IsPressed}"/>
                        </BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                    </BulletDecorator>-->
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="HasContent" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="4,0,0,0"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Source" TargetName="image" Value="Resources/checkbox-dogear-checked.png"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="#FF00D212"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseCaptureWithin" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="#FFA200FF"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: I would just style the CheckBox as the triangle bit, and do the rest of the control as something else like a `ContentControl`

Answer (score 3):

I think Rachel's answer is the right way to go, and since it's not something I've quite tried before, I thought I'd have a crack and knocking up a quick attempt (criticism welcome).

I didn't have the images you were using, so I used a `Polygon` and a `Path` to mockup the tickbox instead - so the style became this:

```
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SelectedCheckboxColor" Color="#FF00D212"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="UnselectedCheckboxColor" Color="Gray"/>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                        <Border x:Name="border" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="{StaticResource ResourceKey=UnselectedCheckboxColor}">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>

                                <!-- Tickbox Mockup -->
                                <Polygon x:Name="checkPoly" Points="0,0 24,24 24,0 0,0" Stroke="Purple" StrokeThickness="0" Width="24" Height="24" 
                                         VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Fill="{StaticResource ResourceKey=UnselectedCheckboxColor}" />
                                <Path Stroke="White" Data="M 6,6 L 9, 9 L 16,2" StrokeThickness="2" Margin="0, 1, 1, 0"
                                      VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="HasContent" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="4,0,0,0"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="checkPoly" Value="{StaticResource ResourceKey=SelectedCheckboxColor}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource ResourceKey=SelectedCheckboxColor}" />
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseCaptureWithin" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="#FFA200FF"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

Which was then hosted, along with an `Expander` (with some test content), inside a `ContentControl`:

```
<ContentControl Width="100" Height="100">
        <Grid>
            <!-- Make sure the Checkbox is the foremost element -->
            <CheckBox Grid.ZIndex="99" />
            <Expander Header="Test" >
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="Test" />
                    <TextBlock Text="Test" />
                    <TextBlock Text="Test" />
                </StackPanel>
            </Expander>
        </Grid>
</ContentControl>
```

Which looks like this:

[image]

Your mileage may vary depending where you intend to use the `Control`. One thing to note, the checkbox will still toggle if you click the border - if that's a problem, you could remove the border width from the `CheckBox`, stick it on the `ContentControl`, and use some binding to hook up the `Border` brush color from the `CheckBox`.

Comment: I actually did end up drawing the checkmark area with polygons, since I wanted to be able to change the colors more easily (fine tweaking and things). For the sake of getting a prototype out for review, I ended up making a `UserControl` that emulates the behavior I wanted, which also included revealing itself only when the mouse is over it. But, I do want to transition it to a CheckBox eventually to take advantage of its accessibility features built-in.

Answer (score -1):

perhaps you can set an on_click listener for the checkbox and then check the mouse positions and only change the checkbox state if the mouse is within the correct relative bounds?

Comment: I got to thinking that maybe trying to fit a square peg in a round hole was a bad idea. I might need to turn this into a custom control. It's kindof silly, though, just for that one feature.